# How to repeat code on a pandas dataframe until certain conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of about 70,000 rows that I'm taking a random sample of 533 rows based on the weight of a column:'score'. I then use the describe() function on the sample dataframe and I want to keep repeating this whole process until I reach a specific average for one of the columns. So far my code looks like this which I've been repeating manually trying to get to this certain number 1.699.

```
weights={0:.11, 1: 1.5}
df['weightsScore'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: weights[x])
dfsample=df.sample(n=533, weights = 'weightsScore')
dfsample.describe()
```

So far I've been getting close but I want to be able to loop this over and over again until I'm able to get that target mean score and I've tried running this function below but I'm not sure if it's working

```
while df['score'].mean() > 0:
   weights={0:.11, 1: 1.5}
   df['weightsScore'] = df['score'].apply(lambda x: weights[x])
   dfsample=df.sample(n=533, weights = 'weightsScore')
   dfsample.mean()
   if dfsample['score'].mean() == '1.699'
        break
```

I was also wondering if I could do this for multiple columns as well like if I did a describe() function on a dataframe and wanted to get certain values for the averages of different columns

Comment: you have an error where `'1.699'` should be a float instead of a string (remove the single quotes). because of this your `if` will never be true and your loop will not hit the `break`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.